# verify gpg signature without installing key

Tags: command-line, signature, gnupg

How do i verify a gpg signature (cli or w/ node js) without installing the public key? i do have the public key but don't want to add it to the keyring. Any hints?

Thanks,
Florian

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a shell script I use for just that purpose.  It creates a temporary keyring, installed the specified public key in it, runs the specified command, then deletes the temporary keyring.

Note that this installs the key from a keyserver.  It shouldn't be hard to tweak it to use a key you already have on disk (and I should add an option to do just that).

Update: See https://github.com/Keith-S-Thompson/gpg-tmp

```
#!/bin/sh

keyid=$1
shift
case "$keyid" in
    ????????)
        ;;
    *)
        echo "Usage: $0 key args..." 1>&2
        exit 1
esac

tmp_keyring=$HOME/$keyid-keyring.gpg

gpg --no-default-keyring --keyring $tmp_keyring --recv-keys $keyid
gpg --no-default-keyring --keyring $tmp_keyring "$@"
rm -f $tmp_keyring
```

It acts like the `gpg` command, but takes an extra initial argument specifying the 8-digit key id.

Sample usage:

```
$ gpg coreutils-8.9.tar.gz.sig
gpg: Signature made Tue 04 Jan 2011 07:04:25 AM PST using RSA key ID 000BEEEE
gpg: Can't check signature: public key not found
$ gpg-tmp 000BEEEE coreutils-8.9.tar.gz.sig
gpg: keyring `/home/kst/000BEEEE-keyring.gpg' created
gpg: requesting key 000BEEEE from hkp server subkeys.pgp.net
gpg: key 000BEEEE: public key "Jim Meyering <jim@meyering.net>" imported
gpg: no ultimately trusted keys found
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1  (RSA: 1)
gpg: Signature made Tue 04 Jan 2011 07:04:25 AM PST using RSA key ID 000BEEEE
gpg: Good signature from "Jim Meyering <jim@meyering.net>"
gpg:                 aka "Jim Meyering <meyering@gnu.org>"
gpg:                 aka "Jim Meyering <meyering@redhat.com>"
gpg: WARNING: This key is not certified with a trusted signature!
gpg:          There is no indication that the signature belongs to the owner.
Primary key fingerprint: 155D 3FC5 00C8 3448 6D1E  EA67 7FD9 FCCB 000B EEEE
```

Keep in mind that this tells you *absolutely nothing* about the trustworthiness of the key, but it's useful as an integrity check.

(I wonder how many keys Jim Meyering generated before he got that one.)

Answer (score 1):

I didn't need much, `gpg --dry-run` (or `gpg -n`) worked for me. I was running gpg 1.4.12 on Mac via Homebrew, but it seems to be a standard option. No idea how it compares to other methods mentioned here.

Comment: That doesn't work for me (gpg 1.4.16, Linux Mint 17). `gpg --dry-run coreutils-8.9.tar.gz.sig` gives me "`gpg: Can't check signature: public key not found`". (I don't have Jim Meyering's key in my keyring.)

Comment: Huh. You're right. Two years later, I can't reproduce it. I tried just about every, e.g. `gpg --dry-run --trust-model direct --keyserver-options auto-key-retrieve --auto-key-locate keyserver --keyserver keys.gnupg.net --verify-options pka-lookups --verify coreutils-8.9.tar.gz.sig coreutils-8.9.tar.gz` but it persists in saying `gpg: Can't check signature: public key not found`. Well, I suppose if you really wanted to avoid a script, you could write the command to instead use a temporary home/keyring and delete it after. But the point of GPG is building trust: that's why they make this hard.

Comment: In GPG's defense, it does say "--dry-run" is half implemented, which is of course what you want to see in such a safety feature. Here, dry-run prevents the command from adding to the keyring, which means verify doesn't ever know what key to use (apparently). When I used it, I must have already had a key added, so the "dry-run" did basically nothing, I suppose. (Oh and `verify-options pka-lookups` just adds additional checks, it doesn't auto-download...)